# Putting the employer's Logo above the Customer

Tags: logo, best-practice

I'm a Front-End Dev with a background in design.

I would like to know if someone would be able to help me finding a good explanation for why I shouldn't put the employer's logo in a place with too much visibility, like the header of a website.  (Because that's exactly what's going on)

I know that this is wrong, but I'd like to have arguments to present to the director of my company, since he's not really open minded to things like this, and he really loves exposing his brand.

In my experience, it shouldn't be in here since we are just developing the website.
Here is an Visual Example: [image: Example]

Comment: I'm really not sure what the situation is here... why is there a website with both an employer's and client's logo in the header?

Comment: I too don't really understand what your'e asking. Can you throw together some sort of visual example?

Comment: Hang on, I'll make a simple illustration and edit the post

Comment: Oh my so many unanswered questions, who owns the page? What is the purpose of the page? Etc etc...

Comment: Cai that's what I'm trying to say. We should NOT have our logo in the header.

@joojaa The owner will be an City Council.

Metis The client accept this positioning, I'm the one who can't bare with this, since I've never seen anything like this. And we are outsourced, giving our services to the government.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's outright "wrong" .. but then.. I hesitate to even attempt such a placement of my branding on a client's web site. If the goal is to promote your web building business above everything else... then it's actually "right" in that respect - even if it is ugly.

If the client(s) is/are aware of the placement and have no arguments regarding it, then I guess the boss is **right**.

Arguments against:

- Aesthetically, it is confusing to readers. How do they know *which* logo represents the company/parent company/subsidiary/etc. Just brand confusion for the **clients and visitors**. But again, if the client(s) fool heartedly agreed to this.. that's *their* branding nightmare, not your employers.
- **Liability** - any claims regarding issues or problems resulting from use or content on the site may just find their way to your employer first and foremost. It's tradition that any branding in the upper left corner is the company responsible for the web site... so If I get cheated or lied to, that's the company I'm going to contact, complain to the Better Business Bureau about, etc.

Other than these, there's just a whole litany of design issues which aren't traditionally anything one can foist upon someone that doesn't understand design. Things like branding conflicts where colors are just not harmonious or style dichotomies... None of which could feasibly be argued without seeing actual imagery. The sad truth is, if 'the boss' just doesn't "get it" you may be stuck with that horrible positioning.

Kind of reminds me of the old phone book trick... name your company "AAA Design" so you appear first in the listings. It will work... but it's "ugly sales" which is a real thing.

Comment: Since it's an government contract, the client don't really have a strong word on this. They don't really care to be fair. 
I think i'll be stuck with this then. Oh well, not going to my portfolio.
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Unless your a company that explicitly put in the contract your logo appears in that positioning.... If I were the client then I would refuse payment until it were removed.

You, as the designer, are obligated to most extents to follow the contract which probably says to meet the client's expectations.

Now if your contract explicitly states this is some "low cost" or "free service" but pay a premium to remove all mention of us than that's a different situation entirely.

---

I'd also tell you that putting your company logo at the bottom footer implies you own the copyrights and trademarks which has all sorts of legal issues.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't even consider paying either. I hate making things as ugly as this. I was just wanting some expert designer opinions to why I souldn't put in the header. But as I can see, I'm kinda screwed. 
Thanks anyway mate!